# Is there a way to have custom UIBarButtonItems in a Toolbar that go against the HIG?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

These are the Human Interface Guidelines for `UIToolBar` Icons, and Bar Button Icons.

I want something that doesn't exactly follow the HIG.

Basically I want a solid rounded and flat colored `UIButton`, with text overtop. (However, I don't want text to be apart of the image for obvious reasons).

Can this be accomplished?

Can you draw a `UIBarButtonItem` with .cornerradius = 5.0. I believe that's`UIButton` only.

Or can you use a masked png image as your `UIBarButtonItem`, apply a tintcolor to change the images mask, and some overlay text on top?

Or would you have to fake/mimic creating a`UIToolbar`, and just create a 44 pixel lightGrey`UIView` at the bottom of your`View`?

How can this be accomplished, and would it be rejected for violating HIG?

Comment: Violating HIG is not a reason to be rejected.

Comment: @chrisP : Kindly let us know if the solution worked for you as you felt it awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always go with the `UIToolBar` & have the `UIBarButtonItem` added to that. Since `UIBarButtonItem` is inherited from `UIBarItem` & then to `NSObject`, you have minimal features to modify.

Use the following code to initiate your items in `UIToolBar`
This way you will have your custom UIButton as a `UIToolBarItem`.

**To change the button background color for different state, you may have to hold the button state toggles in an array, and change the color depending on state**

Here is the fresh code for that:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,55, self.view.bounds.size.width, 55)];
toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
buttonStateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i =0; i < 3; i++){
    UIButton *tempButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
    tempButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    tempButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    tempButton.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    tempButton.tag = i;
    tempButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    [tempButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tempButton addTarget:self action:@selector(displayTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [tempArray addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:tempButton]];

    [buttonStateArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
}

[toolbar setItems:tempArray];
```

**Now the target method of the button**

```
-(void)displayTapped:(UIButton *)sender{
BOOL state = [[buttonStateArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag] boolValue];
[buttonStateArray replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!state]];
if(!state){
    sender.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
}else {
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

}

**Updated Screen here**

[image]

Comment: thanks this is awesome. How would you go about changing the button upon tap? Say lightening/darkening the button color to indicate a tap?

Comment: You will have save the state of the buttons & respectively change the color. Use an array to store the state of all button with some mapping as Tag.

Check for the updated answer.

Comment: @chrisP : Kindly let us know, if the solution worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bar button's `initWithCustomView:` initialiser.

Comment: Would you then supply a UIImageView? How would you overlay text? I'm pretty new, and need this spelled out to me if possible.

Comment: You can create your own custom view with subviews laid out however you want.